# Can't load CSV data into GrapheneDB Instance

Tags: .net, neo4j, neo4jclient, graphenedb

I'm using GrapheneDB to host my Neo4j instance, and am using Readify's Neo4jClient nuget library to connect to it from my locally-running MVC application, like so:

```
var uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Data.csv"));

client.Connect();

client.Cypher
    .LoadCsv(uri, "user")
    .Create("(u:User { Id: user[1], Name: user[2] })")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

This is throwing a LoadExternalResourceException:

> Cannot load from URL 'file:///C:/source/blah/src/App_Data/Data.csv': configuration property 'dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls' is false

Where and how am I to configure this parameter?

Secondly, is it necessary for the csv import file to be accessible from the Graphene DB instance, or is this a client concern?

Comment: Do you need to use MVC/asp.net to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LOAD CSV` clause is executed on the remote Neo4j instance, which has no access to the local filesystem.

In order to load data from a CSV file on the remote instance, there would be two options:

The file would need to be uploaded to the remote server's filesystem and the config setting `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls` should be set to true.

This is not possible on GrapheneDB for obvious security reasons.

Example:

`LOAD CSV FROM file://...`

Solution:

The file is uploaded to a server or cloud service, i.e. AWS S3, Google Docs, Dropbox or your own server. `LOAD CSV` is used with the URL of the file. The file should be publicly accessible so that Neo4j can actually download the file to process it.

Example:

`LOAD CSV FROM http://...`

This would